# Failing to submit archive to itunes connect using Xcode 7 beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode7, xcode7-beta5

When i try to send my archive to itunes connect (upload to app store) i receive the following errors:

[image]

[image]

All of the frameworks mentioned in the errors are installed with Pod. I tried cleaning and rebuilding and try reinstalling all pods. What might be the issue?

Comment: FYI - You can't use beta tools to submit to the App Store.

Comment: I know, but i can use beta tools for internal testing

Comment: try  this solution open googleplus.bundle  remove key `CFBundleExecutable` from  info.plist. Please add google plus framework version